# Create List of Employees with dynamic values using Java streams

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have use case where I have to create List of default employees with incrementing id,

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
int count = 0;
while (count++ <= 100){
    Employee employee = new Employee(count, "a"+count);
    employeeList.add(employee);
}
```

I don't have any collection on which I could use stream. Can we do it in functional way?

Comment: `Stream.iterate(0, n -> n + 1).limit(100).map(i -> new Employee(i, "a" + i)).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) with `rangeClosed(int startInclusive, int endInclusive)` to generate the count

```
List<Employee> employeeList = IntStream.rangeClosed(0,100)
                                       .boxed()
                                       .map(count-> new Employee(count, "a"+count))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or you can use [Stream.iterate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-)

```
List<Employee> employeeList = Stream.iterate(0, n -> n + 1)
                                    .limit(100)
                                    .map(i -> new Employee(i, "a" + i))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: OMG, thank god for downvotes, any chance of emplaning why ?

Comment: Just came across this. It wasn't me but it may have been because you are using `mapToObj` to create state which, based on what I have read in discussions on this site, is a misuse of that method.  I believe I read it on Meta

Comment: Thanks at least sharing that information, i never came across that conversation, do you have any reference or source of that thread? But thanks for sharing that information @WJS

Comment: I'll try to find it because I am now curious too.

Comment: I think I was wrong about creating an instance in a stream operation.  If you mutate existing state within a stream operation it can lead to problems in parallel operations.  But by just creating an instance you are not mutating state because new instances don't modify old instances.  So I think what you are doing is perfectly acceptable.  So I don't know why you were downvoted (which started this discussion). So I ameliorated the situation +1.

Comment: I can only say the same as WJS, it's not clear why this answer has been downvoted. The original version using `mapToObj` was fine. I think, the reasons are non-technical. The question has been downvoted too, so perhaps there were people, thinking that this is a bad question that shouldn't get answers at all. There are such people downvoting all answers when thinking that. On the other hand, I see no close votes. So in the end, we don't know and shouldn't waste too much time thinking about these votes...