# Convert 3 arrays into 1 object array using Streams

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

Lets say I have the following three arrays:

```
int r[] = {255,255,255};
int g[] = {0,0,0};
int b[] = {255,255,255};
```

All arrays **will have same length**.

I want to convert them into an array of objects of type **Color**:

```
public class Color {
   int r,g,b;

   public Color(int r, int g, int b) {
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
   }

}

Color[] arr = new Color[3];
```

Where each index will contain the r,g,b from the same index from the 3 arrays. For example, lets say for `Color[1] = new Color(r[1],g[1],b[1]);`

**How do I do that using Java Streams ?**

The for-loop variant of the code is:

```
Color arr[] = new Color[r.length];

for(int i=0;i<r.length;i++) {
    Color c = new Color(r[i],g[i],b[i]);
    arr[i] = c;
}
```

Is there even a way to do this using streams ?

Comment: What you're really looking for is a `zip` operation on streams, which [was considered but proved impractical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip) because of complications with parallel and potentially-infinite streams. There's not much advantage to using streams instead of the for loop; the loop is more efficient and just as readable.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I dont know about you but Ousmane D's answer, is pretty nice.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- even if there was a `zip` for primitive types or even object types for that matter.... I don't think it would be any better than any of the suggested answers for this specific type of problem mainly because `zip` operates on _two sources_ at a time and as you can see in OPs post ideally a solution where you can operate on all sources in a single function would be much better.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- of-course if there was a `zip` operation (for primitives) for _three_ sources or more then that would definitely be my go to for OPs problem at hand! :). but yes I agree OPs approach is definitely the idiomatic **non-functional** way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IntStream.range` + `mapToObj` then accumulate to an array:

```
IntStream.range(0, r.length)
         .mapToObj(i -> new Color(r[i], g[i], b[i]))
         .toArray(Color[]::new);
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Arrays::setAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll(T%5B%5D,java.util.function.IntFunction))

**Demo:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r[] = { 255, 255, 255 };
        int g[] = { 0, 0, 0 };
        int b[] = { 255, 255, 255 };
        Color[] arr = new Color[3];

        Arrays.setAll(arr, i -> new Color(r[i], g[i], b[i]));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Alternatively**, you can use [IntStream:range](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) to iterate and fill `arr`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int r[] = { 255, 255, 255 };
       int g[] = { 0, 0, 0 };
       int b[] = { 255, 255, 255 };
       Color[] arr = new Color[3];

       IntStream.range(0, arr.length).forEach(i->arr[i] = new Color(r[i], g[i], b[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, the `setAll` is cool. I didn't know that had been added.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [IntStream.range](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) for index sequence, and then use [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) for mapping into `Color` object and finally collect them into array

```
IntStream.range(0,r.length)
         .boxed()
         .map(i->new Color(r[i],g[i],b[i]))
         .toArray(Color[]::new);
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and Ousmane D.'s answer ?

Comment: And why are you using `boxed()` ? Why is that necessary ?

Comment: @ng.newbie not much difference TBH. they're both valid but `mapToObj` is the idiomatic approach in scenarios like this (i.e where you want to map from primitive to object type). basically to convert a stream of primitives to a `Stream<T>`.

Comment: @OusmaneD. and `mapToObj` is more efficient, as `.boxed() .map(i->new Color(r[i], g[i], b[i]))` will convert all `int` to `Integer` first, to unbox them again, as it is equivalent to `.boxed() .map((Integer i) -> new Color(r[i.intValue()], g[i.intValue()], b[i.intValue()]))` whereas `.mapToObj(i -> new Color(r[i], g[i], b[i]))` truly is `.mapToObj((int i) -> new Color(r[i], g[i], b[i]))`

Comment: Thanks @Holger for the feedback, Actually my intention was to use `mapToObj` but i did answered another question using `mapToObj` then my answer keep getting downvotes and recommended to use `boxed()`, can you please correct if my understanding is wrong or if there is something deeper i have to understand https://stackoverflow.com/a/61412082/9959152